# Pgpool install - libpq is not installed or libpq is old

Tags: postgresql, replication, linux, pgpool

Based on the documentation [here](http://www.pgpool.net/pgpool-web/contrib_docs/simple_sr_setting/index.html), I want to create a pgpool II with PostgreSQL databases. When I try to install, I encounter this error:

```
  configure: error: libpq is not installed or libpq is old
```

Searching the pgpool website, they mention to run `./configure` with this command:

```
  --with-pgsql
```

OR

```
   --with-pgsql-includedir
```

OR

```
   --with-pgsql-libdir
```

But still I'm facing the same problem. Can anyone guide me what can I do from here?

I am running PostgreSQL 9.2 intalled from a yum package on CentOS 5.

Comment: What operating system are you running this on? How did you install PostgreSQL? Does the `pg_config` program exist anywhere on your system? It should be on the `PATH`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm running Linux centos 5.And I'm installing through PostgreSQL yum repo. Currently the postgresql version is postgresql-92.there are two pg_config in my machine. one is /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config  and the other one is /usr/src/debug/postgresql-9.2.1/src/bin/pg_config

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of compiling PgPool, why not just install it from package management?

```
yum install postgresql-pgpool-II
```

I don't use CentOS, but that's it's package name in Fedora 17, and the two are usually consistent.

Since you're using a PostgreSQL 9.2 installed via Yum on CentOS 5, you're obviously using a 3rd party packaging of PostgreSQL, so you're likely to be using the [yum.postgresql.org](http://yum.postgresql.org/) repository. This repository claims to contain PgPool-II, so try:

```
yum search pgpool
```

and see if you find any packages. Get details on them with:

```
yum info packagename
```

---

Otherwise, for compiling PgPool you need the development package for PostgreSQL installed:

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

If that alone doesn't do the trick, try making sure `pg_config` is on the `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin
./configure
```

You shouldn't need to specify a `libdir` or `includedir` explicitly, as the're in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` (or `/usr/lib64`) on CentOS and those are default search locations for `configure` and `gcc`. It's most likely that you just don't have the development headers installed.

Comment: If anyone come here by searching problem. If you installed PostgreSQL from source and don't want to install libraries again, you can use --with-pgsql-libdir option.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this command and it will work:

```
./configure --with-pgsql-libdir=/usr/lib(lib directory in pgsql installation folder) --with-pgsql-includedir=path-to-the-dir-where-libpq-fe.h-exists
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).